# How to create self-contained and self-configured python application package using Conan?

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, conan

Here my use case:

- I would like to package some python application, say "pylint", which its configuration (pylint.toml) and everything needed to run it against the script some developers will work
- I need to run pylint both localy (on the env machine) and on the dev env (conan)
- I want a Conan package so that this "capability" is directly available, idealy as a "cmake target"
- I need my app to work on linux and windows
- I do not want to mess with the system neither the user home.

Why not let user do their own virtualenv, manage dependencies, use poetry? Because they are not python developers, they do mistakes, they kill their system environment easily, ...
they are developers on a proprietary test system (or whatever) working in a conan environment that already "packages" some interesting tools dependencies for this system, and C code etc.

So my idea:

- create zipapp package of pylint (i do not want to use pyinstaller, it is really difficult to maintain on the long run)
- export the self-contained executable and pylint.toml and cmake script into a conan package
- the cmake script would provide targets that can be easily called from my main dev environment to lint some script files.

I would like to know if I want something completely irrealistic or does it makes actually sense, and if someone has done similar things?

I will later do the same for mypy, flake8, black, isort, and then other proprietary programs.
My fallback idea, is to not package the zipapp application, but just check is the system wide application is installed and in the right version, but this make is impossible to have CI with different version of pylint installed running at the same time on the same runner (Gitlab).

I like self-contained application with dependencies I update (not the developers), even for python.